# Can't get disable twitter bootstrap dropdown item

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, dropdown

I am trying to do an advanced search to filter what I am looking for. So, I am using a bootstrap dropdown to select my filter and I want to disable some dropdown items according some conditions. But I already tried some approaches and I can't figure out why it doesn't works.

```
        <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
          <li><a class="enabled" id="filter_a">Search by A</a></li>
          <li><a class="enabled" id="filter_b">Search by B</a></li>
          <li><a class="enabled" id="filter_c">Search by C</a></li>
          <li><a class="enabled" id="filter_d">Search by D</a></li>
        </ul>
```

So, for disable the first item which I have id="filter_a" I tried:

Set class="disabled" in HTML code and the command bellow with no success.

```
$('#filter_a').addClass('disabled');
```

**Live Demo:**
https://jsfiddle.net/gheleri/mL2btnws/1/

Comment: So what do you want to be disabled? and your fiddle doesn't show anything but the html.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to add the class to the father 'li'

```
$('#filter_a').parent().addClass('disabled');
```

Comment: Thank you very much! You save my day :)